# Ошибка URL: [Errno 10061] Подключение не установлено, [команда вернула код 255

Tags: bitbucket, mercurial

Не получается подключиться к серверу Bitbucket (пытаюсь протолкнуть на сервер Mercurial свою ветку) выводится следующая ошибка:

> Ошибка URL: [Errno 10061] Подключение не установлено,
>   [команда вернула код 255 Wed Aug 01 21:55:40 2018]

В чем основные причины могут быть? Забанили на Bitbucket или где-то есть информация о тех. профилактике?

Comment: Вообщем получилось, но с 31-го раза, кто пользуется Bitbucket и Mercurial, поделитесь знаниями, у вас такое происходило ?

Comment: Такая же ситуация, причем в браузере без VPN не заходит на bitbucket.org, а клиент на локальной машине обращается думаю к тем же серверам что и сайт в браузере.

Comment: У меня такая же проблема

Comment: Блин придется разориться на впн.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

РКН заблокировал сеть 18.204.0.0/14, в ней 3 IP адреса принадлежат bitbucket.
Но есть еще 3 адреса, которые не заблокированы: 104.192.143.1, 104.192.143.2, 104.192.143.3

Нужно, чтобы bitbucket.org их резольвил, вот так нужно прописать в /etc/hosts:

`104.192.143.1 bitbucket.org`

В Windows нужно сделать то же самое, только там файл hosts в другом месте лежит.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! А вот тут можно глянуть IP-адреса битбакета https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/what-are-the-bitbucket-cloud-ip-addresses-i-should-use-to-configure-my-corporate-firewall-343343385.html

Comment: в Windows файл лежит в `%WinDir%\System32\Drivers\Etc`

Comment: Остальные IP теперь тоже заблокированы

Comment: Сегодня эти 3 адреса не работают, работает по bitbucket.org

Answer (score 1):

Со вчерашнего дня не работает. Даже сайт https://bitbucket.org
При этом через VPN заходит. Видимо в России он заблочен.